# HTML5 <header><div><footer> simply stacked

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I've been struggling with this far too long now.

What Im trying to do is simply get the follow stacked as you would a table with 1 column, 3 rows. Im trying to abandon old HTML and CSS methods for the prefered HTML5 page structuring methods.

Like this...but with nothing overlapping...

```
 ----------------------------
|    | header           |    |
|     ------------------     |
|    |                  |    |
|    | content          |    |
|    |                  |    |
|     ------------------     |
|    | footer           |    |
-----------------------------
```

What happens is the footer ends up overlapping the content, and the content is larger than the page itself (which makes sense as it is 100%...). I've tried some of the work-arounds involving the 'stickyfooter' but I cant seem to get it working...I thought I'd restart from the ground-up - what should I know? Is there something obvious that I am missing?

CSS:

```
header{
background-color: #000000;
height: 200px;
width 1000px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto; 
}
.content{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto; 
}
footer{
background-color: #000000;
width 1000px;
height: 200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
 Header Content
</header>
<div class="content">
 Page Content goes here
</div>
<footer>
 Footer Content
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vHAIm) of what you are trying to accomplish.

```
header, footer, .content {
  background: salmon;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.content{
  background: white; 
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

In your code, you are missing colons in the `header` and `footer` (`width 1000px;`), and you didn't define the `width` of `.content`.

You can also combine selectors with a comma, and use the `margin` shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your margins like this:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

This will result the top and bottom margins being 0px and left and right margins centered, like you have it now.

I can't help but think your content/footer issue is caused by the height of your content section being 100%.  I like setting height either to a specified length, or to auto.  Auto allows you to not know the height when the page is rendered but will accommodate accordingly.

Also setting the width of your content section will make it centered like the rest of your page.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of snooping around the web, I managed to get what I needed working, including a sticky footer, all css3 and html5 compliant. You can see this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2f9M/). Nonetheless, the code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
  <title>
   Title
  </title>

  <style type="text/css">
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
   }

    * {
       padding:0px;
       margin:0px;
   }

   #backColor1, #main, #copyright {
    width: 900px;
   }

   #backColor1 {
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: -1; 
    left: 50%; 
    height: 32767px;
   }

   #backColor2 {
    position: relative; 
    left: -50%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: #FF0000;
   }

   #main {   background-color: #FFCCFF;
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
   }

   #wrap {
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   }


   #header {
   background-color: #0000FF;
   height: 150px;
   width: 100%;
   }

   #nav {
   height: 40px;
   background-color: #FFFF00;
   }

   #footer {
    position: relative;
       margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
       height: 150px;
       clear:both;
       background-color: #333333;
       text-align: center;

       } 

      #copyright {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      }

   /*Opera Fix*/
   body:before {
       content:"";
       height:100%;
       float:left;
       width:0;
       margin-top:-32767px;/
   }

/*
##########################################################################
*/   

  #footer #copyright p {
   font-family: verdana;
   color: #AAAAAA;
   text-align: justify;
   font-size: 0.7em;
  } 

  </style>

<!-- ie sticky-footer fix !-->  
  <!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->


 </head>
<body>

<div id="backColor1">
    <div id="backColor2">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
     <p>
      header
     </p>
    </div>
    <nav id="nav">
     <p>
      Link1 Link2 Link3
     </p>
    </nav>
 <div id="main">
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </p>

 </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
 <div id="copyright">
 <p>
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
 </p>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```